# Displaying errors for rails has_many through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following class:

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :parenthoods
  has_many :children, through: :parenthoods, index_errors: true

  has_many :childhoods, class_name: 'Parenthood', foreign_key: 'child_id'
  has_many :parents, through: :childhoods, source: :person
end
```

With an explicit join-table model:

```rb
class Parenthood < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'Person'
  validate :parent_can_not_be_child
  private
    def parent_can_not_be_child
      errors.add(:person, "child can not be parent") if person_id == child_id
    end
end
```

I would prefer to keep working with a `has_many :through` as opposed to a habtm if possible. And it seemed to the most reasonable way to create the association. The update action in the controller is pretty straight forward:

```rb
def update
  @person = current_user.people.find(params[:id])
  if @person.update_attributes(person_params)
    redirect_to @person
  else
    render action: 'edit'
  end
end
```

And in the view I have (HAML, but it seems pretty clear in its intent)

```
-if @person.errors.any?
  = @person.errors.full_messages.first
```

The update action has the following behaviours:

- Input is all OK: Works as intended ✔️
- Name validation fails: Shows a validation error in the form template as you would expect ✔️
- Try to make somebody their own child: Instead of showing the validation error on the form it, I instead get the 500 error page with this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in PeopleController#update
>
> Validation failed: Person child can not be parent

I'm sure there is an easy way to handle this in rails but I just seem to be going around in circles at the moment, any help appreciated lots!

Comment: I think you should add the error to the `base` or `person_id` instead of `person` association: `errors.add(:person_id, "child can not be parent") if person_id == child_id`

Answer (score 1):

> Try to make somebody their own child: Instead of showing the
>   validation error on the form it, I instead get the 500 error page with
>   this error:
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in PeopleController#update Validation
>   failed: Person child can not be parent

You have `= @person.errors.full_messages.first` which means *it always shows only **first** error message*. You should instead loop through it to show *all error messages on the form*

```
- @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
  = msg
```

***Update:***

> add(attribute, message = :invalid, options = {}) public

As **@gabrielhilal** mentioned in the comments, the first parameter of the [*`add`*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors/add) should be an `attribute`. So change `:person` to `:person_id`

```
def parent_can_not_be_child
  errors.add(:person_id, "child can not be parent") if person_id == child_id
end
```

And add `validates_associated :parenthoods` to `Person` model to show up that validation error in the list of `@person.errors`

Comment: My issue isn't that only one error is shown. But that I see my 500 error page. Deleting all error display code or changing it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Hello @pavan - Thanks for the update, I found adding the error to `:base` `:parent` or `:parent_id` doesn't resolve the issue. Including all permutations of `validates_associated` combined with `:children, :parenthoods, :childhoods, :parents`. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much to @Pavan for pointing me in the correct direction! The fix is to write this as the validation method:

```
def parent_can_not_be_child
  person.errors.add(:base, "child can not be parent") if person_id == child_id
end
```

And then include the validates associated validator on the person object:

```
validates_associated :parenthoods
```

The key is that adding the error to *person* not to the *parenthood* means the error is displayed in @person.errors later.